# PostCSS compiling SASS media queries out of order?

Tags: css, sass, media, breakpoints

I'm using a simple webpack build with PostCSS. If I don't declare a specific media query mixin in the first section of the page's SCSS, but use that specific media query mixin in a following section, that media query outputs **after** the other breakpoints (even though I have them defined in a specific order in my mixins file). Here's my code:

**_variables.scss**

```
$sm-screen: 576px;
$md-screen: 768px;
$lg-screen: 992px;
$xl-screen: 1200px;
```

**_mixins.scss**

```
@mixin sm-screen {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$sm-screen}) {
      @content;
  }
}

@mixin md-screen {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$md-screen}) {
      @content;
  }
}

@mixin lg-screen {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$lg-screen}) {
      @content;
  }
}

@mixin xl-screen {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$xl-screen}) {
      @content;
  }
}

@mixin screen-size($screen) {
  @media screen and (min-width: $screen) {
      @content;
  }
}
```

**_page.scss**

```
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// HERO SECTION
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  #hero-section {
    .hero-heading {
      font-size: 2rem;
    }

    @include sm-screen {
      .hero-heading {
        font-size: 5rem;
      }
    }

    @include lg-screen {
      .hero-heading {
        font-size: 6.5rem;
      }
    }

    @include xl-screen {
      .hero-heading {
        font-size: 6.5rem;
      }
    }
  }


// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// INTRO SECTION
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  #intro-section {
    .icon-group {
      background: red;
    }

    @include md-screen {
      .icon-group {
        background: yellow;
      }
    }

    @include xl-screen {
      .icon-group {
        background: blue;
      }
    }
  }
```

**main.scss** (importing files)

```
@import "/base/variables";
@import "/base/mixins";
@import "page";
```

As you can see in `_page.scss`, I like to declare breakpoints right within each section (or row) as I go down the page. The problem is since I didn't declare the `@include md-screen` breakpoint on the first section, `HERO SECTION`, it comes after the `@include xl-screen` breakpoint in the output CSS and overrides the styles of the largest breakpoint:

**output CSS:**

```
body.home #intro-section .icon-group {
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  body.home #intro-section .icon-group {
    background: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  body.home #intro-section .icon-group {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Does this mean that my practice of declaring the breakpoints on each section is not the best way? Should I declare all breakpoints at the end of each file, that way if nothing changes in one section at a specific breakpoint, I don't need to declare that breakpoint at all to get it to compile in the correct order? Is there a way to get media queries to output in the order they're declared in the mixins file, regardless of when the mixins are called in the CSS?

My intent is to get the breakpoints to output from smallest to largest since I'm using the mobile-first, min-width approach. I would love to apply the media queries like I'm doing, but if there's a better way (such as at the end of files), so be it.